# Laravel Double n:m relation

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have a problem creating a "Double" n:m relation in Laravel.
First I have two tables called locations and services. These tables have a n:m relation and a table called location_service. The table has an incremental id and an id of each table.

In the Models I have the following Code:

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function locations(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('app\Location','location_service','service_id','location_id');
    }
}


class Location extends Model
{
  public function services(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('app\Service','location_service','location_id','service_id');
  }
}
```

In addition, I created a table called tags. This table tag can be linked to several location_service and several location_service can be linked to different tags. I created a table called location_service_tag with an incremental id, the id of the location_service and the id of the tag. But how should I do the model? The point is, that there is no Model like app\Location_Service.

Comment: For myself I would create a model called `LocationService` which has 3 realtions `service() as belongsTo`, `location() as belongsTo` and `tags() as belongsToMany`. This makes it much easier to assign or remove tags from `LocationService` because you have a seperated model

Comment: So if I understand you right, you would create a completely new table with all three IDs? When I think about your solution, do not all must have the relation belongsToMany or am I wrong? 

One Example is: Location has SBux and CoCo, Service has cook and delivery, tags has quick and friendly. All combinations should be possible like (SBux, cook, quick // SBux, delivery, quick // CoCo, cook, friendly // CoCo, cook, quick...).

Comment: If you make it like I described it in my first comment you have the id of `service` and `location` in `location_service` both with `belongsTo` relationship and a the tags are related by a `belongsToMany` through a `location_service_tags` table. So all in all you have 4 models `Servic`, `Location`, `Tag` and `LocationService` and 5 tables `services`, `locations`, `tags`, `location_services` and `location_services_tags`

Comment: Ok, I just did that. But I am not sure right now how I can e.g. call the tags in the view. E.g. I have a view with a specific location. There I call the services with a foreach loop. How can I then show in addition the tags that belongs to them?

Comment: Ok, finally I got that problem fixed. Now I don't go through `$location->services` to show all `services`, I now take two loops to go throug `$location->locationservices`, then I show the service with `$locationservice->service` furthermore I had to add into the location model the function `locationservices` with `hasMany(app\LocationService)`. Finally I had to do a loop through `locationservice` to show all `tags`.